# Do US universities publish an official definition of what constitutes a particular race/ethnicity in the context of scholarships or admissions?

Tags: united-states, minority

As an example, let's say someone with 1/16 of African American heritage applies for a minority scholarship and claims themselves as African American. Would they be rejected, all other factors being equal? If so, do universities generally publish a guideline of what constitutes a particular race in the context of scholarship applications or college admissions?

Note that this question is of practical value as there are presumably millions of people of mixed heritage living in the US at the moment.

Comment: Such things are usually done entirely by self-identification, since the prospect of requiring someone to prove their race/ethnicity would be seen as extremely distasteful.

Comment: @NateEldredge so someone of 1/16 of African American heritage can apply if they feel to belong to that ethnic group event though they look 100% Caucasian?

Comment: @JonathanReez, what you _look like_ has little bearing. First Peoples can and do, in fact, often look Irish, or African, or Hispanic, or... In fact, in the sad history of US race relations 1/16  African heritage was just, simply, Black. People could often "pass" as white, but if it were revealed that a great granddaddy was black it would be a death sentence in many places. That is the underlying reason for such rules. But don't claim what you don't believe yourself to be just for a scholarship. Be yourself.

Comment: If you are from Prague, however, then it is likely that your ancestry, even if partly African, won't mean anything for such scholarships. You won't be African American.

Comment: @Buffy I'm not applying for any scholarships myself, just trying to understand how the university figures out who's a minority and who's not.

Comment: In the US we have a lot of minorities. We are moving toward a non-majority society, though many resent it. However, not all minorities are disadvantaged, though many once were. Irish and Italians were once heavily discriminated against in the US, but the African American and First Peoples negative experience was quite extreme and that has not actually completely ended. If _you_ come to the US you would be in "a minority". Many of us celebrate the richness of the society that affords. But we still have a ways to go.

Comment: @Buffy yes, but how would you define who's "African American" and who's not? And after creating the definition, how does one prove that they are actually X% African American? DNA tests?

Comment: The US is not as rule-based legalistic as Northern Europe.

Comment: The comment of @NateEldredge above is correct. We don't try. My own ancestry shows some surprising things. And, I think most DNA tests are only approximately accurate. We don't try to define it, but sometimes we argue about it - especially if someone seems to be intentionally representing themselves as someone they aren't. But even in some of those cases, family tradition has given them a picture of "who they are". Generally we respect that personal sense.

Comment: @Buffy so if you say you're African American, you are African American? If so, does this mean anyone could claim themselves as such at college applications regardless of who their ancestors are?

Comment: Non-resident aliens (e.g. students her in the US on student visas) are recorded as being in a separate category from the racial categories used in Department of Education statistics.

Comment: Someone who looked like me would be questioned on it if I tried. I might have to tell a bit of my family history. But that is a rare occurrence (it has happened) as few would claim membership in a community that is still discriminated against. Most people only claim to be part of a community if they have "lived the life" of that community. An African immigrant to the US now probably wouldn't think of herself as African American (maybe Kenyan), but her kids might. It would depend on their self perceived life experience. If I lie and am discovered I'll be laughed off campus.

Comment: @Buffy but what does "discovered" mean? I presume there would be a hearing and you'd have to present some evidence at said hearing. What would that evidence be and is a list of accepted evidence published somewhere?

Comment: No, there typically wouldn't be any formal process to revoke the scholarship if the recipient wasn't "really" part of the group.  But there'd be severe social pressure on the recipient to return it.  People don't need a hearing or formal evidence to decide how to treat someone socially.

Comment: @NateEldredge so it's up for the "mob" to decide if you're a minority or not?

Comment: @JonathanReez: If you want to put it that way, then yes.  But that's a general feature of society, and not at all specific to academia.

Comment: @AlexanderWoo No, instead it's up to individuals to interpret the vague guidelines as they see fit to further their own biases (see the voter suppression laws that plague the US's history, for example).

Comment: Related: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/118824/is-it-acceptable-to-claim-a-different-gender-or-race-in-the-context-of-college-a

Answer (score 7):

The short answer is no. There is no definition. Our history is very complicated around race and after several hundred years we are still grappling with it. There may be a bit of abuse of the system, but not enough to cause people to try to start defining one another with rigid rules that we would not accept in any case. We have enough problems without that.

In places where such definitions have been used, some of them lead to atrocities. There are current examples in the world now, actually.

Comment: It's worth noting that while this may be the case for most ethnic/racial minorities in the US, it is not universally true. Native Americans, for instance, are often asked to establish their ancestry and prove they are registered/enrolled with a federally-recognized tribe.

Comment: @Sparksbet, is that true in general or just so that the tribe recognizes them? Some tribes generate some wealth that is distributed to members. Some tribes in the US are treated as sovereign due to old treaties. Most were once at war with the US, though not all.

Comment: I don't know the particulars, as I have no native ancestry myself. However, I recall peers in college reporting they tried to apply for scholarships based on native ancestry and were unable to because they were not registered with any tribe (due to the ancestry being too remote or on the wrong side of the family, etc.)

Comment: In Canada at least, "Indian Status" was defined along patrilineal lines, and a indigenous woman who would marry a non-indigenous man could also lose her status. This was designed with the stated intention of eliminating the identity of indigenous peoples in NA. My understanding was that similar rules were put in place in the US. So with that particular ethnicity it's a bit more complicated than self-identification and some amount of genealogy is necessary for the government to recognize someone as "Indian". Maybe the universities don't require proof, but I am not native so I can't say for sure

Comment: @CuriousFindings, yes, such rules are pernicious. Most of the First Peoples formed matrilineal societies. In these societies you clan comes from your mother. For a male, the clan knowledge was given to you by your mother's brothers, not your father, who was required by custom to be in a different clan altogether.

Answer (score 7):

As a general rule, American universities are [required](https://www.vpaa.uillinois.edu/cms/One.aspx?portalId=420456&pageId=440951) to follow [reporting guidelines published by the U.S. Department of Education](https://www2.ed.gov/policy/rschstat/guid/raceethnicity/questions.html) and the [Equal Employment Opportunity Commission](https://www.eeoc.gov/policy/docs/qanda_race_color.html) (part of the US Department of Labor), asking for demographic data about students, employees, and applicants, as partial documentation of their adherence to various titles of the Civil Rights Act, which prohibits discrimination on the basis of race, ethnicity, and several other criteria.

The Department of Education's guidelines include the following [definitions](https://nces.ed.gov/statprog/2002/glossary.asp) (emphasis in the [original](https://nces.ed.gov/statprog/2002/glossary.asp)):

> - An **Asian** person has origins in any of the original peoples of the Far East, Southeast Asia, or the Indian subcontinent, including,
>     for example, Cambodia, China, India, Japan, Korea, Malaysia, Pakistan,
>     the Philippine Islands, Thailand, and Vietnam.
> - An **American Indian or Alaska Native** person has origins in any of the original peoples of North and South America (including Central
>     America), and who maintains tribal affiliation or community
>     attachment.
> - A **Black or African American** person has origins in any of the black racial groups of Africa. Terms such as "Haitian" or "Negro" can
>     be used in addition to "Black or African American."
> - A **Hispanic or Latino person** is of Cuban, Mexican, Puerto Rican, Cuban, South or Central American, or other Spanish culture or origin,
>     regardless of race. The term "Spanish origin" can be used in addition
>     to "Hispanic or Latino."
> - A **Native Hawaiian or Other Pacific Islander** person has origins in any of the original peoples of Hawaii, Guam, Samoa, or other
>     Pacific Islands.
> - A **White** person has origins in any of the original peoples of Europe, the Middle East, or North Africa.

Similar definitions are included in [EEOC sample self-reporting forms](https://www.eeoc.gov/employers/eeo1survey/sample_self_identification.cfm).  Some universities offer [mild](http://www.indiana.edu/~affirm/race.shtml) [revisions](https://www.diversity.pitt.edu/affirmative-action/race-and-ethnicity-definitions) of the federal definitions (for example, removing the optional label "Negro" and replacing "American Indian" with "Native American").

The Department of Education standards allow, and the EEOC standards *require*, asking each applicant (for education or employment) to **self-identify** their own race(s) and ethnicity(ies).  In particular, the guidelines explicitly allow each respondent to specify multiple races and/or ethnic groups.  The definitions are *guidelines* for the applicants to help them self-identify.

So, to answer the original question: If an applicant self-identifies as African American, they **are** African American for purposes of statistical reporting to the federal government.

Comment: As stated elsewhere, our history is very complex. I'll make two notes. One is that reporting is optional by an individual. You can just decline to answer the question. Universities report what data they get and don't make assumptions about those not reporting. The other point is that some Native peoples (First Peoples) reject the terms American Indian and Native American as offensive since they contain the term American, which is a term created by invaders who caused the deaths of about 90% of the original population. (The 90% figure is scientifically supported.)

Comment: I'll also note that, since we each have two parents, it is possible to be many (even all) of these things simultaneously. But less likely that you "identify" with all of them simultaneously.

Comment: It isn't the list that is "complex". It is the history. Yes, it is haphazard. It is also "self reported" and only if you wish to report. It isn't something imposed on you. The purpose of the reporting to the government is that some funds may be available to schools in some situations if they educate a large fraction of "historically underrepresented" people. We've had a racism problem here since the first settlers landed on the shores. The money is a feeble and inadequate attempt to respond to it. BTW, a Brazilian is unlikely to self report Hispanic, and a Jamaican could report Black.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Yes, unfortunately I do find it _normal_, despite its obvious stupidity.  It's probably best to think of this as a list of _irrelevant labels Americans have used to discriminate_, rather than "races" in any scientific sense.  People **do** discriminate against prospective students and employees (and tenants and...) because they are "black" and/or "Hispanic" and/or "Asian"; describing exactly what the discrimination criteria are reveals their stupidity, but does not make that discrimination any less real. (1/2)

Comment: @NajibIdrissi (2/2) A hundred years ago, this list would have included "Irish" and "Polish" as separate categories.  In a few decades, perhaps the list will grow to include "Arab-American", or the government will start asking people to self-report religion to track anti-Muslim discrimination.

Comment: So if, say, a British immigrant who's ancestors lived in Europe for 10+ generations self-identifies as "black", he can freely choose "black" based on his own view of the world?

Comment: One note is that minority-focused scholarships are often funded by private foundations, who can set their own criteria as they see fit, and in particular don't have to use these definitions.

Comment: @Najib, if you think these definitions are bad you should have seen the definition of "black" published by my university's students' union around the turn of the millennium. I can't remember the exact wording, but it was in terms of descent from a group which had been historically oppressed. I wrote to them at the time to comment that I had never previously known that I was black, but on the basis of my Irish ancestry I appeared to qualify.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: I think you're mis-parsing. As I read JeffE's comment, he meant "perhaps [the list will grow to include 'Arab-American'] or [the government will start asking people to self-report religion to track anti-Muslim discrimination]"; not "perhaps ([the list...] or [the government... religion]) to track...".

Comment: @NajibIdrissi That's certainly not my intention!  As Mark suggests, I'm suggesting that the government might start tracking anti-Arab discrimination (by adding "Arab" to the list of races and/or ethnicities), *or* that they might start tracking anti-Muslim discrimination (by asking about religion).